# Formula to script

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Can anyone help me make this script:

```
row.push(('' + data[j][i]).replace(/.*?_/, '').replace(/.*?0*(\d+).*?/, '$1'));
```

do as this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(H2:H);iferror(regexextract(H2:H&"";"\d+")+0);))
```

Formula removes all letters and return only first number (example - 1+2p will be returned as 1, example2 - 25+10z will be returned as 25)

Comment: `Setformula`? Maybe

Comment: That means i need one extra column where to put formula that will return right data from imported data, and I have more then 100 000 rows, every extra column increases load on spreadsheet, that why i wanted script.